# Python Selenium add_cookie from txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scripting

I'm currently utilizing selenium in my python script. As per the code below, I'm adding cookies to my driver, however, I have quite a lot of cookies already loaded into a txt file called cookies.txt (see below) which I'd like to also add. I'm looking for a way so that I can create something like: `driver.add_cookie(cookies from text file)`. Any help is appreciated!

**Current add_cookies code:**

```
driver.add_cookie({"name": "__ibxl", "value": "1"})
```

**What cookies.txt looks like:**

```
[
{
    "domain": ".nike.com",
    "expirationDate": 1552017842,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "__ibxl",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "1",
},
{
    "domain": ".nike.com",
    "expirationDate": 1558353842,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "__ibxu",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "1",
    "id": 2
}
]
```

Comment: is this json format in cookies.txt?

Comment: yes it is json format

Comment: this is a `cookies.json` file. to load a `cookies.txt` file you would use [http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar) and then convert `cookiejar._cookies` to `driver.add_cookie(x)` and from `driver.get_cookies()`. see also [Python: How to load cookies from .txt to selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77742054/10440128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `cookie.txt` you can have `cookie.py` and import it to your main program file.

cookie.py

```
cookies = [ { "domain":"xxx" }, {"domain":"yyy"} ]
```

main.py

```
from cookies import cookies
driver.add_cookie(cookies[0])
```

It's way simpler than manually parsing the file, or opening the file and using it.

Comment: That seemed to work except in cookies.py one of my cookies is  `"hostOnly": false` and it's giving me the error "name 'false' is not defined". Any way around this?

Comment: I would suggest you to double quote `false` inside your cookies.py, because false is not a valid python statement, `False` is, but it's gonna be boolean data type, and I don't think you need it in boolean type.

Comment: @AngusTimoney follow [infernion's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485922/4693568)

Answer (score 1):

You could use json module to parsing your file.

Something like this should work:

```
import json
with open("cookies.txt") as cookie_file:
    cookies = json.load(cookie_file.read())
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Also it's important that you should be at page with similar domain before adding cookies. (`driver.get('nike.com')` in your case)