# Selenium cookie handling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I may have gone about this with the whole wrong approach, if so please do guide me to a better path.
I'm trying to fetch all the announcements from my university webpage, and have them printed out by a discord bot (this I can do successfully).

However, I'm stumped with handling the cookies after a login has been made.

```
# scrapeCSUP.py

import pickle
import time
import pprint
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
assert opts.headless

main_url = "https://cs.up.ac.za/courses/COS132"
browser = Chrome(options=opts)

page = requests.get(main_url)

soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')


def save_cookies(driver, location):
    pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), open(location, 'wb'))


def load_cookies(driver, location, url = None):
    cookies = pickle.load(open(location, 'rb'))
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
    url = "https://cs.up.ac.za/courses/COS132" if url is None else url
    browser.get(main_url)
    for cookie in cookies:
        browser.add_cookie(cookie)


def user_login():
    browser.get("https://cs.up.ac.za/login?next=%2Fcourses%2FCOS132")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/input').send_keys(
        'username')
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input').send_keys(
        'password')
    checkbox = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input')
    if not checkbox.is_selected():
        checkbox.click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input[3]').click()

    save_cookies(browser, 'cookies.txt')
    print("Logged in successfully")

    time.sleep(5)
    pprint.pprint(browser.get_cookies())

    browser.quit()


def login_w_cookies():
    load_cookies(browser, 'cookies.txt', main_url)
    browser.get(main_url)

    time.sleep(5)
    pprint.pprint(browser.get_cookies())


def announcement_printer():
    whole_content = soup.find(class_='siteContainer')

    announcements = whole_content.find_all('div', class_='left')

    for announcement in announcements:
        print(announcement, end='\n' * 2)


browser.get(main_url)
#user_login()
login_w_cookies()
announcement_printer()
print("========================================\n")
```

I run `user_login()` to save the cookies then I perform the `login_w_cookies()`, but I, however, I'm not loading the cookies correctly and that makes me sad.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/DiscBot/scrapeCSUP.py", line 75, in <module>
    login_w_cookies()
  File "E:/DiscBot/scrapeCSUP.py", line 57, in login_w_cookies
    load_cookies(browser, 'cookies.txt', main_url)
  File "E:/DiscBot/scrapeCSUP.py", line 33, in load_cookies
    browser.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "E:\DiscBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 894, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "E:\DiscBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\DiscBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'
  (Session info: headless chrome=81.0.4044.113)
```

Comment: If you can also share cookies.txt to check what all contents are there, error is clear that while adding the cookie there is some issue. Mostly looks like format issue. Check this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485724/415749

Comment: Any updates? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `load`-function add the following lines:

```
...
for cookie in cookies:
    if isinstance(cookie.get("expiry"), float):
        cookie["expiry"] = int(cookie["expiry"])
    browser.add_cookie(cookie)
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain or link me to documentation on why that was needed, or how I can improve the loop

Comment: It's a bug in the `get_cookies()`-method (according to changes related to W3C compliant mode (the default)). Here are the details: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3331.
It will be released with a version of 83 of `chromedriver`.