# Python: How to load cookies from .txt to selenium get webdriver to log in to secure site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

There are two similar questions to mine, however, neither of them has helped me get past this current roadblock in my application.

Main Issue: I am automating the process of logging into several secure websites and downloading files using Selenium. However, because selenium uses a new browser every time it runs, the site does not recognize me and rejects the login input, sending a security verification email.

1) Associated site cookies are in a txt file, that I manually created by exporting the necessary site cookies from my regular Chrome browser. NOTE: I am not sure if it is properly formated because I just took the cookie from Chrome and pasted it to a txt file and that's it.

2) How to properly import and execute those cookies while performing the driver.get(link) function?

Please help, thank you very much!

Main Function Example:

```
from Users/las/Desktop/Python/AF Project/Admin import Load_Cookies
driver = webdriver.Chrome ("/Users/las/Desktop/Python/Selenium/chromedriver")
Load_Cookies(driver, 'filePath')

link1="https://www.website.com/login"
link2="https://www.website.com/secured/commissions-overview"

driver.get(link1)
driver.find_element_by_id("NdbxLoginForm_username").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id("NdbxLoginForm_password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_name("loginButton").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='resultsFound']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a").click

driver.get(link2)
s1 = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Select account to view") 
s1.select_by_value('715116142')
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-primary btn-block-xs col-sm-3").click
driver.find_element_by_id("scicommlink").click
```

Answer (score 1):

to export cookies, you can use a browser extension like [EditThisCookie](https://www.crx4chrome.com/extensions/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg/)

depending on the cookies file format, you will need different solutions
to load cookies to [driver.add_cookie](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie)
and to save cookies from [driver.get_cookies](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookies)

`driver.add_cookie` and `driver.get_cookies` expect this `cookie_dict` format

```py
{
    # required values
    "name": "some-name",
    "value": "some value",

    # optional values
    "domain": ".some.domain.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1738301311.731403, # UTC timestamp
    "httpOnly": True,
    "secure": True,
    "session": False,
    "sameSite": "Lax", # or "Strict"
}
```

a `cookies.json` file can be parsed with `json.load`.
see also [How to save and load cookies in Selenium?](https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-in-selenium/)
see also [Python Selenium add_cookie from txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485560/python-selenium-add-cookie-from-txt-file)

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# save cookies
Path('cookies.json').write_text(
    json.dumps(driver.get_cookies(), indent=2)
)

# load cookies
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/63220249/10440128
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
for cookie in json.loads(Path('cookies.json').read_text()):
    # no. this would raise InvalidCookieDomainException
    #driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    if 'expiry' in cookie:
        cookie['expires'] = cookie['expiry']
        del cookie['expiry']
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setCookie', cookie)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.disable', {})

driver.quit()
```

`driver.add_cookie` is bad, see also [How to preload cookies before first request with Python3, Selenium Chrome WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220248/how-to-preload-cookies-before-first-request-with-python3-selenium-chrome-webdri)

a `cookies.txt` file can be parsed with [http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar).
see also [Using cookies.txt file with Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742899/using-cookies-txt-file-with-python-requests)

`SeleniumMozillaCookieJar.py`

````py
# NOTE this is not perfect...


from http.cookiejar import MozillaCookieJar, Cookie
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union


PathLike = Union[str, "os.PathLike[str]"]


class SeleniumMozillaCookieJar(list):

    """
    load/save cookies from/to a cookies.txt file with selenium

    convert between http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar and list of cookie_dict

    ```
    from SeleniumMozillaCookieJar import SeleniumMozillaCookieJar
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")

    cookiejar = SeleniumMozillaCookieJar()

    # copy cookies from driver to cookiejar
    # cookiejar is a list of dicts
    cookiejar.extend(driver.get_cookies())

    # save cookies
    cookiejar.save("cookies.txt")

    # load cookies
    cookiejar.load("cookies.txt")

    # copy cookies from cookiejar to driver
    for cookie in cookiejar:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)

    driver.quit()
    ```

    author: Milan Hauth <milahu@gmail.com>
    license: MIT License
    """


    def load(self, file_path: PathLike):

        file_path = Path(file_path)

        jar_1 = MozillaCookieJar()
        jar_1.load(file_path)

        self.clear() # delete old cookies

        for cookie_1 in jar_1:
            cookie = {
                # required values
                "name": cookie_1.name,
                "value": cookie_1.value,
                # optional values
                "domain": cookie_1.domain,
                "path": cookie_1.path,
                "expires": cookie_1.expires, # UTC timestamp
                "httpOnly": True, # TODO?
                "secure": cookie_1.secure,
                "session": False, # TODO?
                "sameSite": "Strict", # TODO "Lax" or "Strict"
            }
            self.append(cookie)
            #driver.add_cookie(cookie)
            #await driver.add_cookie(cookie)

        del jar_1


    def save(self, file_path: PathLike) -> None:

        file_path = Path(file_path)

        # save cookies
        jar_1 = MozillaCookieJar()

        for cookie in self:
            name = cookie["name"]
            domain = cookie["domain"]
            path = cookie["path"]
            cookie_1 = Cookie(
                0, # version
                name, # name
                cookie["value"], # value
                None, # port
                False, # port_specified
                domain, # domain
                False, # domain_specified
                False, # domain_initial_dot
                path, # path
                False, # path_specified
                cookie["secure"], # secure
                cookie["expires"], # expires
                False, # discard
                None, # comment
                None, # comment_url
                {}, # rest
            )
            if not domain in jar_1._cookies:
                jar_1._cookies[domain] = dict()
            if not path in jar_1._cookies[domain]:
                jar_1._cookies[domain][path] = dict()
            jar_1._cookies[domain][path][name] = cookie_1

        jar_1.save(file_path)

        del jar_1
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickle to load/write the cookies to a file. This works for me, if it doesn't for you, come back to me:

Run this code once to dump the cookies into a file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle

driver.get("test.com")

with open("cookies.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), file)
```

then, do this to load the cookies:

```
...
with open("cookies.pickle", "rb") as file:
    cookies = pickle.load(file)

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

I hope this will do the job :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried using pickle before posting my question and I was not able to use it. My hunch is that it doesn't work because I need to be logged in to get the right cookies, and thus can't log in without the cookies first so I need to already have the cookies from my private browser before launching selenium. I hope I am making some sense and happy to hear more feedback on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to navigate to the page to set the domain, then add each cookie by iterating the cookie jar:

```
driver.get("https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/titolari.html")

for c in session.cookies :
    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value, 'path': c.path, 'expiry': c.expires})
```

Comment: I am not familiar with how to do this, and there are so many cookies that add each one to the code would greatly reduce the readability. do you have any further input on how to do this? I have been searching online and trying unsuccessfully for days to get around road block.